# Apple ios Safari bookmark favicon does not work, add to desktop works

Tags: ios, favicon

I am trying to get favicons on IOS (10.2) and safari to work. When I am on my webpage and click "add to desktop" icon is shown and added. But when I try to create bookmark, I get 1 letter placeholder image instead. AFAIK same icon should be used for both bookmark and "add to desktop" tile..

I have this in my head element:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?v=asdf">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?v=asdf">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?v=asdf">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?v=asdf">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png?v=r0RW">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=r0RW">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=r0RW">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json?v=r0RW">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=r0RWdpQrAk" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=r0RW">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I am running testing it on pythons SimpleHTTPServer and both request to bookmark and "add to desktop" are going correctly through.

```
10.0.8.109 - - [11/May/2017 18:01:05] "GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?v=asdf
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But no icon is actually shown in safari for bookmark..

Comment: maybe it working normally but safari can't get the icon? is there any basic authentication?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should open `/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?v=asdf` in your browser, just to make sure the icon is valid (really an image, really 120x120...).

If that works, the issue is probably from iOS Safari. This browser is sometimes lazy when it is expected to show the icon of the bookmarked site. Two things you can try:

- Retry the "add to home screen". As crude as this sounds, this is actually a good thing to do. Especially if you previously visited your own site many times while it didn't have an icon yet. You can see this as a "super icon caching issue".
- Try with another iOS device.

Comment: I had no luck with that. I am trying IOS emulator at https://www.browserstack.com and behaviour is the same. Add to home screen works, add bookmark does not. Even though server is being requested for the same image both times..

Specifically, I am using this image https://www.seznam.cz/media/img/seznam-icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png (because it works for them, I though that my image might be somehow invalid, but that is not the case, because seznam's image has same incorrect behaviour on my page..)

Comment: You could give a try to RFG's favicon checker: https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker . Although it cannot pretend to be bulletproof, I am not aware of any case where it says an icon works whereas it actually don't. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this tool.

Comment: Well the favicon checker gave good results, but the apple-touch-icon didn't show up in iPad Safari.

Comment: @Cerveser Maybe a cache issue? Does it still fail or is the icon finally working after a few days?

Answer (score 1):

These are the files requested by Safari upon adding a bookmark:

```
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Just make sure all of them are functional and it should work.